# TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView not expanding when subview (UITextView) expands

Tags: ios, layout, uiscrollview, storyboard, autolayout

`TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` has been working great in keeping the keyboard from blocking my `UITextViews`: but only when the size of the `UITextViews` are static. Now that I am trying to improve my design to make the height of the `UITextViews` grow with the content, `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` is not growing to accommodate the growing `UITextViews`. Has anyone here ever used the `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` with growing `UITextViews` successfully? For the layout, I just use “reset to suggested constraints”.

My particular case is that the `UITextViews` can grow so that the parent needs to grow beyond the dimensions of the device to show all the `UITextViews`. Presently that is not happening. Once a `UITextView` grows, it simply extends beyond other views so that I cannot see the other views.

**UPDATE**

Following is the code I am using to resize the UITextViews. Besides that, there is nothing significant in my code. I build everything in the StoryBoard as per normal. I drag and drop my child views into place: 5 imageViews, two textViews, and three labels. In the viewController `.m` file itself, I am using the following delegate method code:

```
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString
*)text {   [self resizeTextViewToFitContent:textView]; }

- (void)resizeTextViewToFitContent:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGRect frame = textView.frame;
    frame.size.height=[self heightOfTextView:textView]+5;
    textView.frame=frame; }

-(CGFloat)heightOfTextView:(UITextView *)textView {
    CGRect reviewTextFrame = [textView.attributedText boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(textView.bounds.size.width, MAXFLOAT)
                                                                   options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                                                   context:nil];
    return CGRectGetHeight(reviewTextFrame); }
```

Comment: Sir, it's VERY hard to help you without you providing any code... How did you implement it?

Comment: TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView is a drop-in solution. You don't actually have to do much "implementing". In the storyboard you simple set the `custom class` of your view controller `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`. That's it. Then it's supposed to move TextViews out of the way. Here is the link https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: If I don't use `reset to suggested constraints` and if I don't resize my TextViews to grow with the content, everything works fine. So the only difference is that I am changing the height of the TextViews dynamically by change the height in code as `textview.frame.size.height=newHeight`.

Comment: I know what `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` is. My question is how are you implementing the rest of it. i.e. the UITextViews, code for "growing" them, and how are the controls added to `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView`...

Comment: Where are you setting the content size of the ScrollView? You're asking a question about a scrollView, yet I see no code about a scrollView... When are you setting the contentSize? how are you updating it?

Comment: Hhmm. I didn't do that and it used to work, for months now; that is until now that I am trying to resize. Let me look at the example again to see where I am supposed to set the size. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should update the `scrollView`'s content size. Otherwise I don't see how should `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView` know that you're increasing the content size. You should have a method similar to this:

```
-(void) updateContentSize: (CGSize *) newSize {
    self.scrollView.contentSize = newSize;
}
```

and call it whenever you update the size of a `UITextView`.

Comment: Sorry for bothering so much. But how are you getting `newSize`?

Comment: Thanks. I am now able to make the scrollview longer by setting the height to 1000. But as my textViews grow, they still cover each other as opposed to simply grow and stay grown. So maybe I am not having a different auto-layout problem. Basically while I type the view grows and covers the other views, bus as soon as I move to another cell, the view that grew shrinks back. But the children do not fill the parent. But thanks for the scrollView bit. Essentially my problem is not solved. But maybe it's a different layout issue.

Comment: If the problem is not solved, you are not supposed to accept the response. When someone else comes here looking for help, they will expect the response to work. But feel free to up-vote; however, you should un-accept. Clearly Armin makes a great deal of effort to help you, so I understand you feel grateful. But he is helping because he cares, not for points. So please un-accept until an response solves the problem. I actual encountered similar problem in the past; I can't recall if or how I solved it.

Comment: @KatedralPillon - Note that I'm updating the `contentSize` of the `scrollView`, NOT the `frame` or its height!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so if you have problem with the layout of UITextViews INSIDE the `scrollView`, then you have to use AutoLayout, and read [Apple's Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013309-CH1-TNTAG3) on the matter. The link explains why AutoLayout might be tricky to use inside an `scrollView`, and proposes 2 approaches to implement. Hope this helps.